# Determine distribution of a new test statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, statistical-power, clinical-trials, two-sample

Question from my course project:

Suppose we are conducting a two-arm trial. For the control group, there are $n_c$ patients, and their outcome is denoted by X, which has distribution $N(\mu_{c},\sigma^{2})$. In the experimental group we have $n_{e}$ patients and their outcome is denoted by Y ~ $N(\mu_{e},\sigma^{2})$. We are given historical information for standard control with $n_{h}$ patients and mean value $\mu_{h}$. We assume the variance $\sigma^{2}$, is known.

We are interested in testing $\theta=\mu_{e}-\mu_{c}$, the difference in the mean between the experimental group and control group. We formulate the null and alternative hypotheses as:

$H_{0}:\theta=0$ versus $H_{1}:\theta>0$

When not considering historical data, the test statistic is

$T_{1}=\frac{\bar{Y}-\bar{X}}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n_{e}}+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n_{c}}}}$

which follows N(0,1) under $H_{0}$.
When under $H_{1}$

$T_{1}|H_{1}\sim N(\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n_{e}}+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n_{c}}}},1)$

and then I can derive power function and sample size calculation base on the above normal distribution.

So my question is, since I do want to use the information from historical data, Bayesian conjugate analysis suggests that the posterior mean of treatment effect under control group can be estimated by $\hat{X}=\frac{n_{c}\bar{X}+n_{h}\mu_{h}}{n_{c}+n_{h}}$, and the posterior variance is $\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n_{c}+n_{h}}$.The test statistic becomes $T_{2}=\frac{\bar{Y}-\hat{X}}{\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_{c}+n_{h}}+\frac{1}{n_{e}}}}$

I am interested in finding the power function and sample size calculation using the new T. But first, what would be the distribution of the new test statistic? I thought I could use bootstrapping to get the new distribution but is there an easier way to do this?